# Upsert query for JanusGraph which will issue an update to storage backend only if vertex properties are modified

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have the following Gremlin upsert query for a given vertex which **does not** issue an update to the JanusGraph storage backend if the property values for `age` or `city` has not changed.

```
Vertex marko = (Vertex) traversalSource.V()
        .has("person", "name", name)
        .fold()
        .coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addV("person").property("name", name))
        .choose(__.not(__.has("age", age)), __.property("age", age))
        .choose(__.not(__.has("city", city)), __.property("city", city))
        .next();
```

I tried to refactor this to make it more **generic**, with the property changes specified **using a map**.

```
Map<String, Object> propsToUpdate = new HashMap<>();
propsToUpdate.put("age", age);
propsToUpdate.put("city", city);
Vertex marko = (Vertex) traversalSource.withSideEffect("propsToUpdate", propsToUpdate)
        .V()
        .has("person", "name", name)
        .fold()
        .coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addV("person").property("name", name))
        .as("v")
        .select("propsToUpdate")
        .unfold()
        .as("updateProp")
        .select("v")
        .choose(__.not(__.has(__.select("updateProp").by(Column.keys).toString(),
                        __.select("updateProp").by(Column.values))),
                __.property(__.select("updateProp").by(Column.keys),
                        __.select("updateProp").by(Column.values)))
        .select("v")
        .next();
```

Unfortunately this generic query does issue an update to the storage backend even if none of the property values have changed.

Any clues as to why this difference in behavior between the 2 queries? Any suggestions to fix the generic query to make sure an update is not issued to the storage?

I am using **JanusGraph 0.6.2** for these tests.

Comment: The queries differ because the unfold() after "propsToUpdate" generates multiple gremlin traversers that refer back to "v" and possibly change it. However, it sounds strange that anything would be updated to the storage backend before committing the transaction. How do you know?

Comment: "@rpg monitors the network traffic to infer updates to the storage backend, see: https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/-5-3yLOZKQY

Comment: @HadoopMarc yes thats correct. I used wireshark. A CQL BATCH Message is posted to the storage from JG server when an update happens. This message is seen for the map based query (i.e. the second gremlin) but missing for the first query; in both cases when there are no actual updates to the properties.

Comment: And are the transactions committed in both cases, with the update to the storage backend after the commit?

Comment: The application connects to a remote JG server - https://docs.janusgraph.org/interactions/connecting/java/. There are no explicit transactions used (not sure if that is even possible for remote connections); rather the traversals are sent to the server using the terminal steps. So yes, the transactions are committed in both the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition inside `__.has(__.select("updateProp").by(Column.keys).toString())`
does not return the key of the updateProp, but rather returns the string representation of the bytecode of this anonymous traversal. This makes this condition always false (and its negation true) and the property is always updated.

I do not believe gremlin allows to retrieve a vertex property using an as() variable, neither in the context of a has() step nor in a where() step.

Possibly, your generalized query will be possible in JanusGraph-1.0 which will use TinkerPop 3.6.1. In this TinkerPop version it is possible to pass a Map to the property() step. This will make it easy to create a local temporary vertex inside the transaction from the propsToUpdate and compare it to the existing vertex. Only, in case of a difference you pass the Map to the property step for the existing vertex, drop the temporary vertex and commit the transaction.

Comment: I was expecting `__.select("updateProp").by(Column.keys).toString()` to return the key from the updateProp Map.Entry - as per https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.5.3/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Column.java#L47
So `__.has(__.select("updateProp").by(Column.keys).toString(), 
 __.select("updateProp").by(Column.values))` should end up invoking __.has(<key as String>, <value as Object>) similar to the a hardcoded __.has("age", age). Shouldn't it?

Comment: If the has step would take a GraphTraversal for getting the key `__.select("updateProp").by(Column.keys)`  would work, but it does not. toString only gives a String representation of the GraphTraversal object, see https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/groovy/jsr223/dsl/credential/__.html

Comment: @HadoopMark thanks for clarifying! Will wait for JanusGraph 1.0!!

Comment: There is a release candidate available, see: https://lists.lfaidata.foundation/g/janusgraph-users/topic/announce_janusgraph_1_0_0/95535557

Comment: Hi Marc, please can you elaborate/provide a gremlin on how to compare the temporary vertex properties with the existing vertex properties?